# Synonym IIS version with Windows version?

Tags: discussion, tags

IIS is unique in the sense that the version that ships with an operating system is the only version available for that operating system. Windows 2000 Server got IIS 5, 2003 got IIS 6, 2008 got IIS 7 and 2008 R2 has 7.5.

Does it make sense to synonym the IIS version (or somehow make some other relationship) so that users that favorite [windows-server-2008-r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) tag also see [iis7.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis7.5) in their favorites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While they are version-locked, there are very significant topical differences between the two tags. To people who only care about the web-server, following the [windows-server-2008-r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) tag will yield quite a bit of stuff they don't give a hoot about and may not be able to help with. By having a focused tag on [iis7.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis7.5) those people who are interested in web-server config, but not user VSS shenanigans, will be able to follow a much more relevant tag.

I believe this is one case where a focused tag is appropriate.

Comment: I would agree -- IIS is a specialist subset of Windows (Even though IIS is version-locked I consider these questions to be the same as an Apache question: for the most part the underlying OS isn't the issue, it's something specific to the web server software itself that I'm trying to fix)